# GIF to FLV software on GNU/Linux (or cross-platform)

Tags: linux, video, conversion, flv, gif

Do you know how to convert an animated GIF (only two pics in loop) to FLV or AVI?

I didn't search for a Microsoft alternative that maybe could run with WINE, because I really prefer a native one; also a java version will be fine.

Comment: So guys, I wish I could give the bounty to all of you! I found the right way to achieve what I was trying to do by mixing your commands.

 The result is "convert input.gif -coalesce 'frame%02d.png'" and "ffmpeg -r 1 -i 'frame%02d.png' output.flv". (I gave a +1 to all of you, but for the bounty...I really don't know!) Thanks again to everyone that helped me so far, you are really great!

Comment: You should pick one randomly. :)

Comment: Maybe I should answer to myself with the right code, and then give to me the bounty! :D But I suppose that will go to the guy with more votes, instead.

Comment: From the FAQ: "The highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be automatically accepted. Half the bounty will be awarded to the owner of that answer." --- Why the bounty went to JohnT and not to WhiteQuark, since I didn't decided myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ffmpeg should be able to do this all by itself:

```
ffmpeg -f gif -i infile.gif outfile.flv
```

If you prefer a GUI tool, [Format Factory](http://www.formatoz.com/) can do this, and will run under [WINE](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17893).

[image]

No need to worry, it's available in English!

Comment: No luck even with that command...I've tried with different gifs

Comment: @dag729 What about FormatFactory?

Answer (score 6):

Try doing this in console:

```
convert image.gif 'frame%02d.png'
ffmpeg -r RATE -i 'frame%02d.png' movie.flv
```

Replace `RATE` with needed framerate, e.g. 2 for 2 frames per second.

You'll need two packages: `imagemagick` and `ffmpeg`.

Comment: +1, but can't ffmpeg do this in one shot?

Comment: It only translates one frame of gif, and I wasn't able to find any options regarding.

Comment: It doesn't did the trick...all I get is a kind 0f 19:6 (yes, not 16:9) video where you cannot see anything! :D I'm still searching. Thank you for the "convert" advice: I have it but I didn't remember that ImageMagick was that featured!

Comment: Try doing `mencoder "mf://frame*.png" -mf fps=RATE -o output.flv -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=flv` instead.

Comment: same output... :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and ffmpeg :

```
convert original.gif -coalesce out.gif
ffmpeg -f gif -i out.gif result.flv
```

Optimizing the gif with ImageMagick before converting to flv is done to resolve transparency problems.